# How this code translates a number to English?

Tags: clojure

I'm new to Clojure and found there's a piece of code like following

```
user=> (def to-english (partial clojure.pprint/cl-format nil 
"~@(~@[~R~]~^ ~A.~)"))
#'user/to-english

user=> (to-english 1234567890)
"One billion, two hundred thirty-four million, five hundred sixty-seven 
thousand, eight hundred ninety"
```

at https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/partial#example-542692cdc026201cdc326ceb. I know what `partial` does and I checked [`clojure.pprint/cl-format` doc](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.pprint/cl-format) but still don't understand how it translates an integer to English words. Guess secret is hidden behind `"~@(~@[~R~]~^ ~A.~)"` but I didn't find a clue to read it.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The doc mentions it, but one good resource is [A Few FORMAT Recipes](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/a-few-format-recipes.html) from Seibel's Practical Common Lisp.
Also, check [§22.3 Formatted Output](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_c.htm) from the HyperSpec.

In Common Lisp:

```
CL-USER> (format t "~R" 10)
ten
```

- `~@(...~^...)` is case conversion, where the `@` prefix means to capitalize (upcase only the first word). It contains an *escape upward* operation `~^`, which in this context marks the end of what is case-converted. It also exits the current context when there are no more argument available.
- `~@[...]` is conditional format: the inner format is applied on a value only if it is non nil.
- The final `~A` means that the function should be able to accept one more argument and print it.

In fact, your example looks like the one in [§22.3.9.2](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_cib.htm):

> If ~^ appears within a ~[ or ~( construct, then all the commands up to
>   the ~^ are properly selected or case-converted, the ~[ or ~(
>   processing is terminated, and the outward search continues for a ~{ or
>   ~< construct to be terminated. For example:

```
 (setq tellstr "~@(~@[~R~]~^ ~A!~)")
=>  "~@(~@[~R~]~^ ~A!~)"
 (format nil tellstr 23) =>  "Twenty-three!"
 (format nil tellstr nil "losers") =>  " Losers!"
 (format nil tellstr 23 "losers") =>  "Twenty-three losers!"
```